# I need to truncate a table then insert new register, but users cant see this

Tags: mysql, sql, insert, truncate

Its a quite difficult to understand but, theres a table that I need to truncate and in the same time, insert new registers but under this process, the site visitors cant see that theres nothing on websites content, how can I do that in SQL like --single-transation which theres something like "cached registers" before the new one comes?

Comment: Its MySQL  (randomwordsforpostcomment)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [rename table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/rename-table.html) to switch 2 tables.

> RENAME TABLE, unlike ALTER TABLE, can rename multiple tables within a single statement:

- prepare your new table `the_table_next` *(can be a long operation)*
- `RENAME TABLE the_table TO the_table_prev, the_table_next To the_table;` *(very fast operation)*
- drop/truncate table `the_table_prev`

> When you execute RENAME TABLE, you cannot have any locked tables or active transactions. With that condition satisfied, the rename operation is done atomically; no other session can access any of the tables while the rename is in progress.
>
> If any errors occur during a RENAME TABLE, the statement fails and no changes are made.

Note :

with `alter table rename` you need use 2 command ==> 2 different transaction (DDL instruction)

with `rename table` => **single transaction**

Answer (score 0):

If you *can* truncate the table then it's OK to assume that there are no key restrictions on that table. If that is so I would:

- 1) Supposing that the original table is Table1 I would create Table2 with the exact same structure.
- 2) Then I would populate Table2 with whatever I need
- 3) After that, in one transaction, I would change the name of Table1 to Table3 and the name of Table2 to Table1.
- 4) Finally I would whatever I need with Table3 (which was originally Table1).

In MySQL you can rename tables with:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
   RENAME TO new_table_name;
```